# Most efficient MySQL query for not Exists and Sum

Tags: php, mysql, sum, not-exists

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I have this query where I want to fetch `u.id` if the user has over a set amount of hours registered, and does not already have a salary increase registered. In this case only `1` should be the output, because there is no registered `rate_custom` and `num_hours` is more than the `custom_hours` that is `1000`

**I have 3 tables:**
[image: database tables]

This is what I got so far, but I tried parts of it without any luck, so I'm just wondering if there is a faster and more efficient way to deal with this, and one that is actually working?

```
"SELECT u.id "
        . "FROM users u "
        . "LEFT JOIN user_hours uh "
        . "ON u.id = uh.user_id "
        . "LEFT JOIN rate_custom rc "
        . "ON u.id = rc.user_id "
        . "WHERE "
        . "NOT EXISTS (r.crate_id FROM rate_custom r WHERE r.date_added <= NOW() AND r.date_ended IS NULL AND r.user_id = u.id) "
        . "GROUP BY u.id "
        . "HAVING SUM(("
        . "SELECT (THE NUM HOURS WHERE HOUR STATUS IS 4) "
        . ")) >= ("
        . "SELECT rcc.custom_hours FROM rate_custom rcc WHERE rcc.date_ended IS NULL ORDER BY rcc.crate_id DESC LIMIT 1"
        . ")";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the logic correctly, you can do:

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     user_hours uh
     ON u.id = uh.user_id LEFT JOIN
     rate_custom rc
     ON u.id = rc.user_id 
WHERE rc.user_id IS NULL
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN hour_status = 4 THEN num_hours ELSE 0 END) >= 
           (SELECT rcc.custom_hours FROM rate_custom rcc WHERE rcc.date_ended IS NULL ORDER BY rcc.crate_id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

You don't need a subquery to find the non-matches to `rate_custom`; the `LEFT JOIN` does that.  For the `HAVING` clause you can use `CASE`.

Comment: I think this worked! I will come back to it once I have it fully implemented. How would this work for 100K entries in each table?

Comment: @GjertIngarGjersund . . . Assuming you have indexes on the keys for the joins, the `group by` will be the limiting factor in performance.